# Pandas calculate diff() using the value of another column as keyword argument for 'periods'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in which I would like to calculate the diff() on a certain column (Value). The number of periods to be calculated is coming from another column (Periods).

| Periods | Value | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 32 | 0 |
| 1 | 35 | 3 |
| 2 | 37 | 5 |
| 2 | 41 | 6 |

I tried:

```
df['Diff'] = df['Value'].diff(periods=df['Periods'])
```

=> this returns TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

On different posts, I saw that we need to use .astype(int):

```
df['Diff'] = df['Value'].diff(periods=df['Periods'].astype(int))
```

=> but that gives the same TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

I also tried .values:

```
df['Diff'] = df['Value'].diff(periods=df['Periods'].values)
```

=> but that returns the TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Comment: The issue is that the `periods` argument of [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) has to be an integer. You are passing in a collection of integers and it's not clear what is supposed to happen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
df['Diff'] = df.Value - pd.Series(df.Value[df.index - df.Period].values, df.index)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this manually. `reset_index` to ensure your DataFrame has a `RangeIndex`. Then subtract the periods from the Index to figure out which row you need to pull the 'Value' from and map that with the original DataFrame. Now you can manually subtract to calculate the difference, which incorporates the variable 'Periods'.

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df['Value_shift'] = (df.index - df['Periods']).map(df['Value'])
df['Diff'] = df['Value'] - df['Value_shift']
```

---

```
print(df)
   Periods  Value  Value_shift  Diff
0        0     32           32     0
1        1     35           32     3
2        2     37           32     5
3        2     41           35     6
```